# CORS with WebAPI for XmlHttpRequest

Tags: xmlhttprequest, asp.net-web-api, cors

Just wanted to know what is the **best elegant way** (currently available) to handle CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)  in ASP.NET WebAPI so i can use XmlHttpRequest over multiple domains ? How i can integrate this in the headers of every type of request (GEt, POST, etc..) with OPTIONS too ?

Thanks!

Comment: Cross-Origin Resource Sharing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tpeczek have a nice found, however while doing my own research ive found something similar and also very elegant ways of handling CORS which enable you to configure your CORS in a config file in App_Start folder. Its all handled using an open source library called Thinkecture. See details here :

http://brockallen.com/2012/06/28/cors-support-in-webapi-mvc-and-iis-with-thinktecture-identitymodel/

It have many advantages.. you can configure origins, methods (GET, POST, etc.), access to specifics controllers and actions and it also keep your controllers clean from any attributes.

WebAPI, IIS and ASP.NET MVC is supported !

Answer (score 3):

Carlos Figueira has a nice series of posts about CORS and ASP.NET Web API:

- [Implementing CORS support in ASP.NET Web APIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx)
- [Implementing CORS support in ASP.NET Web APIs – Take 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/21/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis-take-2.aspx)
- [CORS support in ASP.NET Web API – RC version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/07/02/cors-support-in-asp-net-web-api-rc-version.aspx)

Personally I'm a big fan of *Take 2* approach because `EnableCors` attribute can be easly extended to give you control over allowed origins.

Comment: Interesting.. however i think i found something better which meet my needs and more look my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Add below in web.cofig file(inside the system.webserver element).

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, maxdataserviceversion, origin, x-requested-with, dataserviceversion" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

and add below code in global.aspx.cs file

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 200;
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: above solution working for me. but "OPTIONS" request send to the server at first time.

Answer (score 2):

There is now CORS support in the nightly of web api

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2013/04/05/try-out-asp.net-web-api-cors-support-using-the-nightly-builds.aspx

Use [nuget](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget) to:

- Uninstall the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes package.
- Install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package from the nightly builds

Then fix the bindings in the web.config
Then enable CORS

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute())
```

Read more about it on this wiki https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CORS%20support%20for%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API&referringTitle=Specs

**Edit 19-04-2013** Scott Guthrie has blogged about it: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/04/19/asp-net-web-api-cors-support-and-attribute-based-routing-improvements.aspx

Comment: A new tutorial has been added to the web api documentation. They have integrated the nigtly cors changes into the main nuget repo. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

It depends how fine-grained you want to control CORS. If you want to allow any domain for instance you can add static CORS headers to all responses by configuring them in IIS. I chose this approach and [wrote about it here](http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/cors-and-iis).