# mvc webapi cross domain post

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CORS with WebAPI for XmlHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732147/cors-with-webapi-for-xmlhttprequest)

I'm trying to implement cross-domain ajax post to my webApi project. I had few troubles with that: 
 1. I always was getting 204 error until changed my webapi action from

```
public void submit(Submission model)
```

to

```
public bool submit(Submission model)
```

don't know why, but now I'm getting `200 OK` status 
 
 2. Still my ajax firing error callback. 
 
 3. Long time ago I solved this kind of error of cross-domain posting by adding

```
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

to my controller. But now in webApi i'm inherent from `: ApiController`  and this trick doesn't work. Shows me compiler `Error an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"System.Web.HttpContext.Response.get"` 
 
 I have tryed to post via `dataType: 'JSONP'` but I get null model. 
 
 Here goes Javascript request:

```
var model = {
        "type": $("#model-type").val(),
        "subject": $("#subject-text").val(),
        "body": $("#body-text").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'JSONP',
        url: $("#submit-url").val(),
        data: model,
        success: function () {
            alert("Succesfully submitted");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error...");
        }
    });
```

What I'm doing wrong?

### SOLVED

Thanks to everybody for helping me out. I found solution in one of the comment links. I used following approach, which I find pretty simple. 
  
Source:
[Implementing CORS support in ASP.NET Web APIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx)

What I made: 
 
1.  Created new Class in my project: `CorsHandler.cs` and just copy-pasted following code:

```
public class CorsHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        const string Origin = "Origin";
        const string AccessControlRequestMethod = "Access-Control-Request-Method";
        const string AccessControlRequestHeaders = "Access-Control-Request-Headers";
        const string AccessControlAllowOrigin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
        const string AccessControlAllowMethods = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
        const string AccessControlAllowHeaders = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";

        protected override Task SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            bool isCorsRequest = request.Headers.Contains(Origin);
            bool isPreflightRequest = request.Method == HttpMethod.Options;
            if (isCorsRequest)
            {
                if (isPreflightRequest)
                {
                    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                        response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());

                        string accessControlRequestMethod = request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestMethod).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (accessControlRequestMethod != null)
                        {
                            response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowMethods, accessControlRequestMethod);
                        }

                        string requestedHeaders = string.Join(", ", request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestHeaders));
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestedHeaders))
                        {
                            response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowHeaders, requestedHeaders);
                        }

                        return response;
                    }, cancellationToken);
                }
                else
                {
                    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage resp = t.Result;
                        resp.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());
                        return resp;
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

2. Opened my `Global.asax` and modifyed  `Application_Start` :

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new CorsHandler());
        }
```

Pay attention to the last line in action. 
 
 This approach is compatible with MVC3 and .NET 4.0. Works great, now I can handle "success" and "error" callbacks in ajax.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?  Can you post a sample of your javascript for this?

Comment: If one of answers from suggested question helped you, you should upvote it, this is how SO works --> http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your questions respectively:

1. Status 204 is not an error, which means no content to return but everything's good. Here's the definition of 204 in [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.5)

> 10.2.5 204 No Content

> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
> entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The
> response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of
> entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the
> requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view
> from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is
> primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without
> causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although
> any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document
> currently in the user agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always
> terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

2. Could you articulate what's the error you met? The ASP.NET Web API currently doesn't have a JSONP formatter out of box. Here's some 3rd part implementation:

- http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Apr/02/Creating-a-JSONP-Formatter-for-ASPNET-Web-API
- http://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApi.JsonP
  I hope they're helpful.

3. In Web API the way in which you refers to an Response is not through HttpContext. There are multiple ways to access.

The first option is to define action return HttpResponse directly.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        var response = this.Request.CreateResponse();
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        return response;
    }
```

The second option is to use ActionFilter:

```
// define action filter for cross domain
public class CrossDomainActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        bool needCrossDomain = true;

        if (needCrossDomain)
        {
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}

// At Controller
// GET api/values/5
[CrossDomainActionFilter]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

The last option is to use [MessageHandler](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers):

```
public class CrossDomainMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Action filter is the most concise! And it uses the extensibility of the framework, so its really the best answer +1

Comment: Oh man . I wish I could vote up again, I keep coming back here :) +beer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send information to another domain from ajax then you need to use jsonp (note this only works with get requests not post requests).  Another alternative (if you are in control of both domains) is to use ARR (application request routing) to trick the browser into thinking the request is local then using ARR to rewrite the request to another domain.  Using this technique you can use simple ajax gets and posts like normal.