# MVC WebAPI Javascript possible cross domain issue

Tags: jquery, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm in the process of building a WebApi - have tested locally, and all works fine.  Deployed to my host machine, and after a few issues of ensuring the ajax call was using the right url to access the webapi, I have hit a problem.

Here's my Razor code that shows the jQuery AJAX call:

```
    string myUrl = Url.Action("Index","Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme, null);


<script type="text/javascript">
    function findByVrm() {
        $('#response').text('Searching...');

        var uri = '@myUrl' + 'api/vehicle';
        var id = $('#vrm').val();
        var call = null;

        // Setup a 'call' object differently depending upon if we want to return
        // JSON data or XML data
        if ($('#rbJson').prop('checked')) {
            call = {
                type: 'GET',
                url: uri + '?vrm=' + id
            };
        } else {
            call = {
                type: 'GET',
                url: uri + '?vrm=' + id,
                dataType: 'xml',
                accepts: {
                    xml: 'text/xml',
                    text: 'text/plain'
                }
            };
        }

        // Perform the API call
        $.ajax(call)
            .success(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                showStatus(jqXHR);

                if ($('#rbJson').prop('checked')) {
                    $('#response').html(vkbeautify.json(response));
                    $('#status').text('Vehicle Found: '+response.data.idscode);
                } else {
                    $('#response').text(vkbeautify.xml(jqXHR.responseText));  // text version of the XML
                }


            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                showStatus(jqXHR);
                $('#response').text('');
            });
    }

    function showStatus(jqXHR) {
        var msg = 'Status: ' + jqXHR.status + '/' + jqXHR.statusText;
        $('#status').text(msg);

        return;
    }          
</script>
```

The HTML is purely a text box with the id of 'vrm', this is the search string, a button which calls the findByVrm() javascript function,  a radiobutton that dictates if the call should return JSON or XML data,  a textbox to display the status of the call, and a textarea to display the content.

When run on localhost, this all works perfectly.  When deployed to the remote host machine, and a call constructed in Fiddler,  it works perfectly.

However when browsing to this page on the remote host machine and making the call through the above code...  the API method is called (I have log messages that show it was called, and that a response was sent back),  the status is updated and shows 200/OK  - indicating to me that the call succeed,  however JSON or XML data does not appear to have been returned in this instance (or if it has been returned, is not visible).

Having researched this on stackoverflow and other sites, I believed it was a 'cross-domain' issue, and have followed other posts about implementing a CORS handler  - and yet, when the webapi is hosted on the remote server and the above Javascript is called, I am still not seeing the response data.

I took the CORS handler code from here: [CORS Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018020/mvc-webapi-cross-domain-post)

Any ideas?

---

EDIT:   Further to the post above and the questions asked below - I've created a JSFiddle to see if I could replicate the issue that I was seeing in isolation - [Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/theboffin/4HvM7/)

The Fiddle WORKS  -- however the above Javascript isn't working - so my initial conclusion here is the vkbeautify is failing, and consequentially quietly exiting the findByVrm() method.

I will perform a bit more testing on this;  but I'd like to thank everyone who's spent time looking at this with me.

---

EDIT: So by removing the vkbeautify.json() call and replacing with a JSON.stringify() and placing the result of that into the textarea  -- this works.

I'm not sure why vkbeautify worked on response data when I was running it in localhost through Visual Studio, but it's irrelevant  -- it'd be nice to be able to 'pretty print' both the JSON and XML responses - but there are other solutions I can look into for that;  this is just a test-bed application, so as long as I can see the response, that's all I need.

Again thank you for all your help.

Comment: Is the domain your ajax request is going to different to the domain the application is running on? If not, then it's not CORS. But can you post up the Request and Response headers from your F12 tools (or Fiddler) for the failed calls, it might give more of a clue...

Comment: Monitoring the traffic with Fiddler @stephen-byrne - I can see in Fiddler that the ajax call made through the jQuery call succeeds with 200 response and the actual data:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authenticate, accept, origin, authorization, content-type
Date: Sun, 27 Oct 2013 10:01:10 GMT
Content-Length: 877

Comment: So I feel the issue is with the 'response' not being visible to javascript in this instance.

Comment: I've just added some trace code,  it is getting back into the .success() function  - for both the JSON and XML versions of the call  - it is just the 'response' is not available/visible to the javascript.

Comment: Can you try adding `contentType="application/json"` option for your JSON ajax call, because this looks very odd in the response header: `content-type Date: Sun, 27 Oct 2013 10:01:10 GMT`. I would imagine that jQuery will not be be happy with that content-type value.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 28 Oct 2013 12:11:17 GMT
Content-Length: 877

Comment: This was captured from Fiddler, as you can see it returned content . valid JSON ... but yet,  the success method from the jQuery call is still unable to see this?

Comment: OK. What browsers have you tried this from? If the data is being returned from the webapi call, then CORS seems to be setup correctly, but something (the browser) is blocking the data before jQuery gets to give it to you. What happens if you manually invoke the remote webapi from the browser, by the way (i.e no CORS)? And also, be aware that the error callbacks in jQuery ajax will not get invoked for CORS.

Comment: Firstly @StephenByrne thank you for your persistence in trying to help me with this issue - it's appreciated.

I've tried both Chrome and InternetExplorer.

If I try to invoke the remote webapi by just using the URL in a browser in Chrome I get back an XML document with my response, all looking correct.

In IE I get back a JSON response.

Noted about the error callback with CORS.

Comment: No problem. Is this webapi url something we could access? Just so I can check using a CORS ajax call and see if I can figure it out?

Comment: Yes, the 'test' web page URL is:  http://81.134.196.28/DataShare
This will call the webapi, with the above ajax code. Try VRM code of S14AWW  (most vehicle registration plates will work, but not all)

The full url to a webapi call is: http://81.134.196.28/Datashare/api/vehicle?vrm=S14AWW&CustomerId=A11D3AC9-8824-4C78-9A94-275A6BD107FC

Comment: @StephenByrne I've added a fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/theboffin/4HvM7/ ,  which works - so I believe the problem is actually in my Javascript and not the webAPI call.  Thank you for your help

Comment: lol you beat me to it, I was halfway through a fiddle when you posted that. Glad to hear you have gotten it working.

Comment: Thanks @StephenByrne  - yes working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, the issue was with [vkbeautify](https://code.google.com/p/vkbeautify/) - for some reason it wasn't working with the remote data;  but was working fine when running locally.

I've now removed the calls to this javascript library, it was only there to pretty-print the JSON or XML returned data.