# What's the login authentication solution for asp.net MVC application and web API service

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I use ASP.net MVC technology in the UI layer and use the MVC web API technology in the service lay(Application layer) and the service layer will be deployed in a different server.

I have used the form authentication in UI lay,what's the login authentication solution for the service layer?
the MVC web API of service layer will be called the by the javascript of UI layer directly,the problem is that I cannot pass the username and password from javascript to web api service for logon authentication ,it's not security and cannot use cookie to determine whether the user is logon,as the web API service is deployed on another server,the cookie cannot cross domain.
Can you give me a solution? Many thanks.

Comment: When you say MVC I take it you mean ASP.NET MVC.  If so it might be useful to edit and clarify your question and retag.  MVC without any additional context is a wide ranging architectural pattern and not a technology specific topic.

Comment: @sam. Does [Authentication between mvc and webapi (Separate domains/Applications)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796570/authentication-between-mvc-and-webapi-separate-domains-applications) help? You haven't mentioned CORS, but this is a good solution to the problem

Comment: Thanks,It is good for me.