# JQuery.ajax does not wait for C# Server's response and calls error function, testing on localhost

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, owin

On the *user-side*, I have a javascript code, that POSTs to the server via JQuery.ajax. On the *server-side*, I receive the request and handle it, but the user-side script does not wait for the servers response and calls *error: getFail* (see below) function.

EDIT: problem was due to having the server and the user-side on different domains, in my case different localhosts. See detailed answer by @Jacob below.
How did I check if the user-side waits for the server or not?
 
I've just run the server in debug mode, and set a *breakpoint* where it receives the POST-ed values. And the user-side already called the error function.

- Could anybody tell me, why it is not working "properly" or what and where is the source of error?

What I suspect to be **one** of *the sources of the "improper" behavior* is the **dataType parameter** of the JQuery.ajax function. It is supposed to specify the expected type of the return value from the server. I am not sure what to set this, so I did not specify hoping the default will find out.

> **[For the dataType parameter]** If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response. Possible types are: xml, html, script, json, jsonp, text, multiple. (Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, JQuery docs).

Here are the codes:

**User-side javascript code:**

```
function logIn() {
try {
    alert('try in logIn');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/Token",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            "grant_type": "password",
            "username": document.getElementById("username").value,
            "password": document.getElementById("password").value
        },
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", // data type sent to server
        // dataType: "json", // data type expected from server <- THIS may be a source of the problem
        success: getSuccess,
        error: getFail
    });
} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
function getSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert(data.Response);
};
function getFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //jqXHR.status is 0
    //textStatus is "error"
    //errorThrown is empty
    alert(jqXHR.status); // <-- THIS is what gets called, instantly after the post.
};
```

};

**Server-side C# code:**

```
public class ApplicationOAuthServerProvider
    : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(
        OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        await Task.FromResult(context.Validated()); // break-point was here
    }

    // This is called by await Task.FromResult(context.Validated())
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(
        OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        // Here manager will have correct values from the POST-ed data
        var manager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        var user = await manager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError(
                "invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            context.Rejected();
            return;
        }

        foreach (var userClaim in user.Claims)
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(userClaim.ClaimType, userClaim.ClaimValue));
        }

        context.Validated(identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post what the error is that you're getting back. What is the error status?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated my question, included the errors I receive in the use-side code as comments.
Also, I will write it here: so I get jqXHR.status is 0.

Comment: Does the domain of the client & the server match? Sounds like cross-origin issues to me.

Comment: I am running on localhost.
User-side is: http://localhost:57116/
Served-side is: http://localhost:8080/
So, I am not sure if they match or not. :/

Comment: Those are considered different origins, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing what the actual error is that you're getting back will confirm/disprove this, but I've seen CORS issues to blame for this. Depending on how the call is being made and what the server supports, you may have a preflight request that is handled by the server as though it was the full request, and then the *client* can reject the response because it wasn't cross-origin authorized.

I'm not sure what your server-side framework is, but this may help if indeed this is a cross-origin issue:

[CORS with WebAPI for XmlHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732147/cors-with-webapi-for-xmlhttprequest/12742101)